# Order Printer not accessing hidden line_item.properties

Tags: shopify, liquid

so I am using the order printer app to generate work orders through Shopify. It lets you build a page with HTML and gives you access to liquid variables in order to pull useful information.

It was all working fine until 2 days ago when it decided to just stop displaying any line item properties where the property was hidden (i.e starts with a '_')

I know that this method is used in order to deliberately hide these properties from the cart which is fine but these would normally still display in order printer until 2 days ago. Now they are gone. All gone.

I have tried the following:

```html
{% for line_item in line_items %}
 <strong> {{line_item.title}}</strong><br />
 {% if line_item.properties == empty %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}<br />
 <strong>Line_item.properties size: </strong> {{line_item.properties | size }}<br />
 <ul>
  {% for p in line_item.properties %}
   <li>{{ p.first }}: {{ p.last }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
 </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

I have run this on orders that have 3 hidden properties (with '_' ) and the `size` returns `0` and the `line_item.properties == empty` returns `True`

I have run it on orders that have 2 hidden properties + 2 blank properties + 3 non-hidden properties and `line_item.properties == empty` returns `false` and the `size` returns `3`unsurprisingly the `p.first` and `p.last` that display are for the 3 properties that are not hidden and have values.

So how can I display the hidden properties? Does anyone know of a workaround for this? Like I mentioned before this was not the case 2 days ago. Previously it would have displayed all properties that had values, even if they were hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that; there was an issue with Order Printer and it has been fixed. The hidden line item properties are now accessible once again.

Comment: Thanks, Josh. I can confirm that this is now working on our store once more.